# Compare columns of two dataframes without merging the dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2.

**DF1:**

```
StartDate

1/1/2013
2/1/2013
11/1/2014
4/1/2014
5/1/2015
```

**DF2:**

```
EmploymentType        EmpStatus           EmpStartDate

Employee              Active              11/5/2012
Employee              Active              9/10/2012
Employee              Active              10/15/2013
Employee              Active              10/29/2013
Employee              Terminated          10/29/2013
Contractor            Terminated          11/20/2014
Contractor            Active              11/20/2014
```

I want the count of rows from DF2 where EmploymentType = 'Employee' and EmpStatus = 'Active' and EmpStartDate<= Start Date of DF1

**Output:**

```
Start Date    Count

1/1/2013      2
2/1/2013      2
11/1/2014     4
4/1/2014      4
5/1/2015      4
```

How do I achieve this without merging the two dataframes?

I cannot merge the dataframes since there are no common keys and since I need the count of rows based on conditions, I cannot join the dataframes on any temporary columns as I need to avoid cross-join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a cartesian join and filtering if your dataframes are too big:

```
(df1.assign(key=1)
   .merge(df2.query('EmploymentType == "Employee" and EmpStatus=="Active"').assign(key=1), 
          on='key')
   .query('EmpStartDate <= StartDate')
   .groupby('StartDate')['key'].count())
```

Output:

```
StartDate
2013-01-01    2
2013-02-01    2
2014-04-01    4
2014-11-01    4
2015-05-01    4
Name: key, dtype: int64
```

#### Details:

- Filter df2 using `query` to including EmploymentType and EmpStatus
  equal to Employee and Active respectively.
- Assign a dummy key to each dataframe and use `merge` on dummy key to create a
  cartesian join of all records.
- Use `query` to filter results of join to only those records where
  EmpStartDate is less than or equal to StartDate.
- Lastly, `groupby` StartDate and `count`.

Also, note that using `query` is a shortcut.  If your column names contain special character or a space, then you'll need to filter your dataframes using boolean indexing.

## Option #2:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2.query('EmploymentType == "Employee" and EmpStatus == "Active"').sort_values('EmpStartDate'), 
              df1.sort_values('StartDate'), 
              left_on='EmpStartDate', 
              right_on='StartDate', 
              direction='forward')\
  .groupby('StartDate')['EmploymentType'].count()\
  .reindex(df1.StartDate.sort_values())\
  .cumsum()\
  .ffill()
```

Output:

```
StartDate
2013-01-01    2.0
2013-02-01    2.0
2014-04-01    4.0
2014-11-01    4.0
2015-05-01    4.0
Name: EmploymentType, dtype: float64
```

Details:

- Use `pd.merge_asof` to join df2 filter down to df1 to the nearest
  forward-looking date.
- `groupby` the start date joined on from df1 and count.
- `reindex` results by df.startdate to fill in missing/zero value for the
  start dates
- Use `cumsum` to mimic <= functionality and sum.
- Use `fillna` to populate missing records with previous sums.

Comment: The cartesian product will increase the number of rows leading to incorrect count. I just want the count of rows from DF2 which satisfies all 3 conditions. So I was looking for a way to compare the columns of 2 dataframes without merging them. I can filter out the "EmploymentType and EmpStatus equal to Employee and Active" rows but I am not sure how to compare the date columns from 2 dataframes without merging.

Comment: @user3252184 Here  is another approach without exploding records from a cartesian/cross join.

Comment: Option 2 worked!!!! But I got the expected output without reindex. Thanks a ton scott :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def compensation(x):
return DF2[DF2['EmpStartDate']<x
 and  DF2['EmpStatus']=='Active'].shape[0]

DF1['Count']=DF1['StartDate']
       .apply(lambda x:  
                   compensation(x),axis=1)
```

The method is Boolean indexing and counting rows.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: It's encouraged to explain what your code is doing.